# Default selected MatChips are not synced with MatChipList selected property

Tags: angular, angular-material2, md-chip

Default selected *MatChips* are not synced with *MatChipList* selected property
Initial selected chips are empty eventhough Lime is selected. When we double click again Chip is getting added in *selected* but not initially.
Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chips-examples-zr53nq)

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you: [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-selected-matchips-are-not-synced-with-matchiplist)

HTML:

```
<mat-chip-list #chipList multiple="true">
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [value]="fruit.name" [selected]="fruit.selected" (click)="onSelectFruit(fruit)">
    {{fruit.name}}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
<div class="hintLabel">Select Fruits</div>
<br/>
  <button (click)="getSelectedChips()">Get Selected Chips</button>
<br/><br/>
<b>Selected Chips:</b>{{array | json}}<br/><br/>
<b>Dynamic Selected Chips:</b>{{arrayDynamic | json}}
```

TS:

```
array: Fruit["name"][] = [];
arrayDynamic: Fruit["name"][] = [];

ngOnInit(){
  for (let fruit of this.fruits) {
    if(fruit.selected){this.arrayDynamic.push(fruit.name);}
  }
}

onSelectFruit(fruit){
  fruit.selected=!fruit.selected
  this.arrayDynamic = [];
  for (let fruit of this.fruits) {
    if(fruit.selected){this.arrayDynamic.push(fruit.name);}
  }
}

getSelectedChips() {
  this.array = [];
  for (let fruit of this.fruits) {
    if(fruit.selected){this.array.push(fruit.name);}
  }
}
```

DEMO:

[image]